# How to convert flash video to screensaver?

Tags: flash, screensaver, swf

I have a flash video that was developed by a third party, but would like to make it into a screensaver.  I know there are tools for this, but have no idea which ones are best, free, etc.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[swfmaestro](http://www.swfmaestro.com/)

> The SWF Maestro software is available in four versions: SWF Maestro EXE, SWF Maestro EXE PRO, SWF Maestro SCR and SWF Maestro SCR PRO. The EXE version is used to create applications (SWF projectors, presentations, programs, games, etc.), while the SCR version is used to create screensavers. The PRO versions are used to create applications and screensavers with 'try-before-buy' limitations. The feature of adding 'try-before-buy' limitations enables you to turn SWFs into profitable commercial products.

It's not free though.

Answer (score 0):

On my experience I've worked with [Creamshavers](http://www.creamshavers.com/) (web service, working with .swf files), and [Flash Screensaver Master](http://www.screensavermaker.com-http.com/download.html)  (it is good, but not free. But there is a trial version if you need it for 1-2 times).